# Transfer airport from narita to haneda

Tags: transit-visas, japan, layovers

Do I need a transit visa from Narita to Haneda? I am holding a Philippines passport and a permanent resident visa in Canada. Does Japan provide transit visa in the airport? Unfortunately I only have 5 days for my flight so I cannot go to the embassy to get a transit visa.

Comment: Based on the below I don’t know if the airline will provide  as it states it requires application by the captain. I am looking for someone who have done this and if they can post their experience                                                        An immigration inspector may grant a foreign national (except for crew members) aboard a vessel permission for landing in transit upon application by the captain of the vessel or the carrier who operates the vessel, when such foreign national wishes to land temporarily for sightseeing purposes while the vessel is in Japan, and to return to said

Comment: The procedure described by @MichaelHampton's linked thread has nothing to do with the "captain of the vessel." When arriving by air and meeting the requirements by showing an onward ticket with 72 hours from suitable airport and documents for that destination — you have all these —  a Japanese "Shore Pass" is issued by the officer at Japanese Immigration.

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs. Highly appreciated.